# Programmatically turn on location in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-location

I want to turn on device location programatically without navigating to the settings screen. There'll be a popup asking for the location. Upon click on the OK button, device location will be turned on. How to do this in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would have to handle the platform-specific location services in your Flutter app. Luckily, people have already developed plugins for you to be able to do that without re-inventing the wheel. One package I've used in the past and I can suggest is [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location), its built on top of the iOS and Android native location services, with a nice Flutter wrapper around them.

Regarding the pop-up with permissions, you would have to handle it yourself for every platform. In the case of the location package, you only need to do it for iOS. You can read more about it in the package's description, in the "Getting started" and "Usage" section.

Answer (score 0):

First u need to use [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) package. Now use this method in init state so that user allow to access the location

```
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
  _checkPermissions();
}

_checkPermissions() async {
    Location location = Location();
     bool permission = await location.hasPermission() == PermissionStatus.GRANTED;
     if (!permission) {
       await location.requestPermission();
    }
}
```

Now use this method to get user location

```
Future<void> _getLocation(bool value) async {
 // show Loading on start
 // loading = true;
 // future Delayed if the user does not grant location second layer permission
 Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), () {
  _error = 'Sorry, enable to get your location. \n Please try again';
});
 Location location = Location();
_locationData = await location.getLocation();
// After getting location do stuff here
}
```